# Travis badge service

Tags: security, travis-ci

So I'm considering creating a quick service for Travis badge. A Travis build would need to make a http call to the service for it to know what to display. Securitywise, how can my service know that it is really a travis build for a specific repo and not just some spammer? Does Travis support some kind of auth challange or something like that? Or will I need to have something my self where you can plop some kind of secret in the Travis config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice project!

Sounds like you want to use webhooks. To ensure you know it is coming from Travis CI, have a look at this: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Verifying-Webhook-requests

Comment: sweet! But how would I get the coverage, e.g. "5%" out? Can I query the build url for artifacts  somehow? I think I want more like a custom webhook, e.g. signed like described in link, but with my own body data...

Comment: Unfortunately not. The webhooks are not triggered from the job VM, but from an internal system, and as an aggregate of all the jobs if you have more than one. One way to go would be to retrieve the build log from the API, and to gather the data you need from that log file on the receiving end. Have a look at this resource: https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/log#find

Comment: Ok, that clears things up. I'll go for a secret then as to not get too travis specific. Can you update answer and I'll accept.